# Sentence separation but not domain names

Tags: python-3.x, regex, split

Can you suggest me a way of separating only sentences divided by dot (.) but not domain names in Python?

For example, I need to divide "Janice is my mother.She is a good mother" but not "google.com" or "shop.tk".

Comment: As domain names are just words separated with dots, there is no perfect answer to this. Think about domain of Montenegro ".me". `.... my mother.Me and my self...`

Comment: Have you attempted this problem? SO is not a code-service website, we will, however, help you with problems you face. I suggest [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to mess around with regexes btw.

Comment: As Jean-baptiste writes theres is not a perfect answer but you might be able to create a whitelist of domain name example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains, as you can see there is a lot of top level domains, so you would not be able to differentiate between words and domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a way to separate sentences by dot(.) except for domain names. I have assumed that every sentence begins with a capital letter and no space in between the first letter and the previous dot(.).

```
import re

txt = "Janice is my mother.She is a good mother and google.com and mother.She"
new_txt=txt
seperated_txt=[]
while True:
    y = re.search(r"[.][A-Z]", new_txt)
    if y==None:
        break
    elif y!= None:
        seperated_txt.append(new_txt[:y.start()+1])
        new_txt = new_txt[y.start()+1:]

print(seperated_txt)
```

Best Regards